# How to get Firestore Data to Show in a Label

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to coding so please bear with me. I have the code in my view controller set to load in a label on the view controller. When the code is ran on the simulator, it prints properly in the console and shows the document ID, first name, and last name, but does not put the first name and last name in their labels on the view controller. What am I missing?

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseAuth

class profileViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet var firstNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lastNameLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        readArray()
    }
    
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func readArray() {
        self.db.collection("users").getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    let docId = document.documentID
                    let firstNameLabel = document.get("firstname") as! String
                    let lastNameLabel = document.get("lastname") as! String
                    print(docId, firstNameLabel, lastNameLabel)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on your example code, the missing are these codes. :)

```
firstNameLabel.text = firstNameLabel
lastNameLabel.text = lastNameLabel
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. Where would I put this exactly?

Comment: Never mind. I added it and it works, but it is showing that last user to sign up, not the current user. How would I make it the current user?

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much!